# Bootstrap NavBar not collapsing as expected - separating onto two lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Question Background:**

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap on my site and have incorporated a collpasing navbar for my sites menu.

**The Issue:**

The `NavBar`collapses to a button as expected but when the screen hits a certain width the logo I have within the `NavBar`and the menu items split onto two separate lines. The following shows the issue:

This is the navbar with the page fully expanded and working as desired:

[image]

This is with the page slightly minimized and response, notice the `NavBar` has now split into two lines. This is **not** the desired behavior I want. I ideally I want the option to stay on the same line or collapse to a button:

[image]

This shows the `NavBar` fully collapsed:

[image]

**The Code:**

This is my `NavBar` markup. I cannot see why I'm seeing the above unwanted behavior with the `NavBar`separating into two lines:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand">FM<b>FC</b></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Welcome">Welcome</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="features">Club</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="About">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Committee">Committee</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="Location">Location</a></li>
                    <li><a href='@Url.Action("FutureEvents", "Events", new { pageNo = 1 })'>Events</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Any help in working out this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nav is wrapping in to 2 lines because you have many menu items and the Bootstrap `container` switches to 750px as the screen width shrinks. You have 2 options..

One option is to use the full width `container-fluid` (this may not work for your design):
http://codeply.com/go/TfbwIivilI

Another option is to decrease the point at which the navbar collapses. This requires CSS to override the default navbar collapse point. In your case around 1000px seems to work best:
http://codeply.com/go/kcaXYh7ARB

Answer (score 0):

It happenes because you have so many `li` elements, so what you need is to change the collapse break point. Just add the following to your css

```
@media(max-width:992px) {
.nav>li>a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px
    }
}
```

[**bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/fthRQCpN7d).